# Combinations and Probability with Duplicates and No Replacements

Tags: probability, combinations

In a hat, there a $2 \times \mathrm{R}100$ bills, $4 \times \mathrm{R}50$ bills, $5 \times \mathrm{R}20$ bills, and $9 \times \mathrm{R}10$ bills. Two bills are drawn from the hat. What is the probability that the sum of the $2$ bills is less than $\mathrm{R}100$?

The answer is $0.68$, but I keep getting $0.77$.

Comment: How do you get your 0.77 ? Also, should the sum be striclty less than 100, or less-or-equal to 100 ?

Comment: And where does the answer 0.68 comes from ?

Comment: While your answer is correct, you should explain your reasoning.  Had there been a flaw in your work, it would be easier to detect if we could see what you did.

Answer (score 1):

Subsets Of Size Two (Number Of Ways To Get Each One):

{10, 10} ($(9\cdot8)/2 = 36$)

{10, 20} ($9\cdot5 = 45$)

{20, 20} ($(5\cdot4)/2 = 10$)

{10, 50} ($9\cdot4 = 36$)

{20, 50} ($5\cdot4 = 20$)

{50, 50} ($(4\cdot3)/2 = 6$)

{10, 100} ($9\cdot2 = 18$)

{20, 100} ($5\cdot2 = 10$)

{50, 100} ($4\cdot2 = 8$)

{100, 100} ($1$)

Probability balls add up to less than R100 $$=\frac{10+20+36+36+45}{6+8+10+10+18+20+36+36+45} = \frac{147}{190} \approx 0.774$$

Answer (score 0):

Your sum is above $100$ if you have drawn at least one of the two R100 bills, or two R50 bills.

If you care about the order, there are $19*20=380$ ways of drawing the two bills with the same odds of occuring.

There are $19*2*2-2=74$ ways of drawing at least one R100 bill.

There $4*3=12$ ways of drawing two R50 bills.

Which sums to $86$ unfavourable cases, hence $294$ favourable ones.

$294/380=0.774$, I agree with your result.

Comment: Two R50 bills don't make "above 100".

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

The number of ways two bills can be selected is 
$$\binom{2 + 4 + 5 + 9}{2} = \binom{20}{2}$$

To select two bills such that the sum of their values is less than R$100$, we must either choose one R$50$ bill and one bill from a smaller denomination or two bills whose denomination is less than R$50$, which can be done in 
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{5 + 9}{1} + \binom{5 + 9}{2} = \binom{4}{1}\binom{14}{1} + \binom{14}{2}$$

ways.  Hence, the probability of selecting two bills such that the sum of their values is less than R$100$ is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{14}{1} + \dbinom{14}{2}}{\dbinom{20}{2}} \approx 0.77$$